# Rails: How to get url like /users/2/events/2009-02.html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

For the caching purpose I can't have url like /users/2/index?month=2009-02 . The problem with this approach is that if I do page caching then same page is returned even for /users/2/index?month=2009-03 .

To solve the caching issue I would like to have url like /users/2/events/2009-02.html . I have defined users to be a restful resource.

map.resources :users

Does anyone know how to get url like /users/2/events/2009-02.html which will map to

controller = users
action = events
id = 2 or user_id = 2
month = 2009-02

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your application's routes file, you can set up a named route like this:

```
map.user_events '/users/:user_id/events/:month.html',
                :controller => :users, :action => :events,
                :requirements => {:month => /[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}/}
```

The routing DSL has changed a lot in Rails 3. Now you would do something more like this:

```
get '/users/:user_id/events/:month.html' => 'users#events',
    :constraints => {:month => /[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}/}
```

There's more information on routing here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html